# Curved Container for the screen - flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a curved container (semi circle) on whole screen using flutter
[image for the curved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkH7.jpg)

I tried to use some solutions found on stackoverflow but it didn't work.
can anyone help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap your widget with stack and then provide clip oval to the container and positioned your container to the left with half of your container width.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: -10,
              bottom: -10,
              left: -200,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  height: double.maxFinite,
                  width: 400,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

**You will get the following output**

[image]